# Updating a multidimensional array in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need some help on how to update a multidimensional array in PHP. I am using the following array to update a grid of images. The number of my images varies.First I upload and resize my images and then save them in the `images` field as Json in database.I set the image size to 300 by default and save it in `thumb` field. This my json images field that i store it in database:

```
[
  {
    "images": {
      "300": "/storage/uploads/300.1.png",
      "600": "/storage/uploads/600.1.png",
      "900": "/storage/uploads/900.1.png",
      "original": "/storage/uploads/1.png"
    },
    "thumb": "/storage/uploads/300.1.png"
  },
  {
    "images": {
      "300": "/storage/uploads/300.2.png",
      "600": "/storage/uploads/600.2.png",
      "900": "/storage/uploads/900.2.png",
      "original": "/storage/uploads/2.png"
    },
    "thumb": "/storage/uploads/300.2.png"
  },
  {},
  {}
]
```

For example, suppose I want to edit the size of the second image and change it from 300 to 600.This is the request log I get from the edit form.

```
array:3 [▼
  "_token" => "wZSerggegrgL1lcbhWZFwerfwerfwerfVx"
  "_method" => "patch"
  "imagesThumb" => array:4 [▼
    "/storage/uploads/300.1.png" => "/storage/uploads/300.1.png"
    "/storage/uploads/300.2.png" => "/storage/uploads/600.2.png"
    "/storage/uploads/300.3.png" => "/storage/uploads/300.3.png"
    "/storage/uploads/300.4.png" => "/storage/uploads/300.4.png"
  ]
]
```

***How do I update the thumb of the second image?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below solution. It was done by playing with `array_flip()` function. Replace *address_to_json_file* with the address of your json data.

```
$request = [
    "/storage/uploads/files/2020/ads/images/300_2020_12_25_26b48.1.png" => "/storage/uploads/files/2020/ads/images/300_2020_12_25_26b48.1.png",
    "/storage/uploads/files/2020/ads/images/300_2020_12_25_12567.2.png" => "/storage/uploads/files/2020/ads/images/600_2020_12_25_12567.2.png",
    "/storage/uploads/files/2020/ads/images/300_2020_12_25_6da51.4.png" => "/storage/uploads/files/2020/ads/images/300_2020_12_25_6da51.4.png",
    "/storage/uploads/files/2020/ads/images/300_2020_12_25_65509.png"   => "/storage/uploads/files/2020/ads/images/300_2020_12_25_65509.png",
];
$sample_json = json_decode(address_to_json_file, true);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($request); $i++) {
    $flipped_arr = array_flip($sample_json[$i]['images']);
    foreach ($flipped_arr as $new_key => $original_key) {
        if (!empty($request[$new_key]) && $new_key != $request[$new_key]) {
            $sample_json[$i]['images'] = $request[$new_key];
        }
    }
}

dd($sample_json);
```

Comment: What do you mean by `address_to_json_file`? You mean the array that is the database. @babak-ashrafi

Comment: Yes. The json data. I spent some minutes on solving your question, please don't waste it.

Comment: i have error => json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: i tried this code but doesn't work. and $sample_json is the same data in database and thumb never changed.`
        $sample_json = $advertisement->images;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($inputs['imagesThumb']); $i++) {
            $flipped_arr = array_flip($sample_json[$i]['images']);
            foreach ($flipped_arr as $new_key => $original_key) {
                if (!empty($request[$new_key]) && $new_key != $request[$new_key]) {
                    $sample_json[$i]['images'][$original_key] = $request[$new_key];
                }
            }
        }
       dd($sample_json);
`

Comment: i log this code `dd(!empty($request[$new_key]) && $new_key != $request[$new_key]);` before if and returns `false`.

Comment: Another thing I have to mention, I want the new size to be saved in the thumb of the same image. Look at the Question i added expected output

Comment: The algorithm works good, but you need some basics of algorithm. You should not pass string to json_decode. You should be aware that the condition in if statement may be true or false and a lot of other things. Overall, good luck

Comment: Thank you, It's doesn't work for me but can you tell me what's out do you expected? i trying to debuging your code

Comment: If doesn't work, don't accept it. I wrote this algorithm to convert every match of `images` array with the `requested` array as you've mentioned in the question. For example, if you pass a 300 =>600, it will convert a 300=>300 to 300=>600. I'd like to give a clue.

Comment: Dear babak, I found that your algorithm seems wrong.plz check out this link http://www.upsara.com/images/m666232_.png  @babak-ashrafi

Comment: Thank you @Reza. I will fix it.